# ElasticSearch MapperParsingException object mapping

Tags: elasticsearch

I folow a article about ElasticSearch and I try put this example on my engine.

example:

```
curl -XPUT 'elasticsearch:9200/twitter/tweet/1' -d '{
    "user": "david",
    "message": "C'est mon premier message de la journée !",
    "postDate": "2010-03-15T15:23:56",
    "priority": 2,
    "rank": 10.2
}'
```

I try to send this information across a bash file (I use Putty), but I have this errror:

```
{"error":"MapperParsingException[object mapping for [tweet] tried to parse as object, 
  but got EOF, has a concrete value been provided to it?]","status":400}
```

I also try to see one error with "cat -e tweet.sh", but I don't understand why I've got this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post your index mapping..

Comment: I think it's because type's mapping mismatches stored document structure.

Comment: There's also a single quote in your input that may be screwing it up.  So, instead of sending the full object, it's only sending '{
    "user": "david",
    "message": "C'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a type mismatching. I'm facing with such issue too. It looks like you try to index a value into an object mapped json. i.e., you indexed one time something like this:

```
{
  "obj1": {
    "field1": "value1"
  }
}
```

and then index this:

```
{
  "obj1": "value"
}
```

Check your existing mapping via `elasticsearch:9200/twitter/_mapping` and you will see if that one of the field was indexed as `object`